# Problem with publishing GIS resources in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server

I have ArcGIS 9.3 on Win 7 sp1 integrated with VB.Net 2008. I have connected my server in ArcCatalog and publish mxd to ArcGIS Server without any problem, put after I open ArcGIS Server Manager and publish GIS services to GIS resources it gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: Go to your logs and post that information also.  It appears that your ArcGIS Server account cannot access the file system that the mxd is located on.

Comment: I am running into a similar problem check you server logs in your server manager under diagnostic. Look for error report. I notice that my ArcSOM keeps stopping, I have not fixed the problem but maybe this information might help you out.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Since this is so brief and inconclusive, it is better to either continue to develop your idea and edit the answer accordingly or add it as a comment (to the question) and delete the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Checking and posting the event log as Jamie suggests would be very helpful.  Based on your description though, it sounds like either the data in your published map document is not on a network resource that the server can see, or the ArcGISSOC user does not have permissions to read the data store. Check the permissions on your data. See the "Grant permissions to data diretories" section in [ArcGIS Server Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Configuring_a_one_machine_deployment/0093000000m6000000/).

Comment: i do not know where is the correct directory log folder, is it in C:\inetpub\logs, if is it i have not any file on this folder,if you mean that in C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\server\user\log, i found many file logs, this is recently log file.

Comment: this is the log file in this directory, C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\server\user\log,<Msg time='2012-01-31T11:21:27' type='WARNING' code='2009' target='Server' thread='3280'>Server.dat is not found.</Msg>
<Msg time='2012-01-31T11:21:28' type='WARNING' code='2011' target='Server' thread='3280'>Server Directory c:\arcgisserver\arcgisoutput is not found.</Msg>

Comment: <Msg time='2012-01-31T11:21:27' type='WARNING' code='2009' target='Server' thread='3280'>Server.dat is not found.</Msg>                                                         <Msg time='2012-01-31T11:21:28' type='WARNING' code='2011' target='Server' thread='3280'>Server Directory c:\arcgisserver\arcgisoutput is not found.</Msg>

Comment: i did full control for ARCSOC and ARCSOM,and the problem is still exist